# Android Toast message display

Tags: java, android, android-layout, toast

I have list of product. When the user click on the  row, the `Toast` msg will be displayed  the name of the product.

I want to display the `Toast` on the each product row line.I want to show the Toast in the place where user click on list' row

See my picture;

[image]
Currently displaying center of List:

I did like this :

```
tablerow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast prName = Toast.makeText(RetailerOrderActivity.this,
            " Name : " + productList.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())).getDescription(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        prName.setGravity(Gravity.AXIS_SPECIFIED, 0, 0);
        prName.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
int[] values= new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
int x = values[0];
int y = values[1] ;

toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd and 3rd params of `setGravity()` are x and y offsets from the constant specified in the 1st param. You will need to get the x&y position of the row view object you wish to position the toast above. Or you could get the x&y of the touch event.

Personally I would start with `setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,0,0)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have an `onClick` or `onItemClick`-listener somewhere. If so, a `View`-parameter is passed to it. The passed `View` is the view that was clicked (the entry of your list). You can get the Y-position of it by using the `getY()`-method.

You should always center the Toast horizontally and let the `Toast` decide it's width.

So your code might look something like this (using an `onItemClick`-listener):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Get the Y-position:
    int y = (int) view.getY();
    // Create the Toast:
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RetailerOrderActivity.this,
        " Name : " + productList.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())).getDescription(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    );
    // Set the position:
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, y);
    // Show the Toast:
    toast.show();
}
```

I did not test it, but it should work.

Comment: I could't `getY()` values using view.(view.getY()) .I am doing inside the TableLayout. `tablerow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View view){
    
       Toast prName = Toast.makeText(RetailerOrderActivity.this," Name : " +  productList.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())).getDescription() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       prName.setGravity(Gravity.AXIS_PULL_BEFORE, 0, 0);
       prName.show(); `  how to take `getY()` value?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your question. I forgot to cast the float returned by `getY()` to an int. See if the code works now.

Comment: I am doing this part in TableLaayout. when each row is selected, then need to do this.how to get the y value using TableLayout `setOnClickListener`.could't get the view.getY()